# datatables - row slide down instead of show

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Im using the above dataTable demo, but Im trying to get the new row to slideDown instead of show? I tried below code, but cant seem to get the row to appear. How can i get this slideDown/slideUp behaviour?

```
row.child('<div class="child-container">'+contactInfo + editorRooms+'</div>').slideDown();
```

**----[ UPDATE ]----**

I then found this:

https://www.datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02

I couldnt get this line to work:

```
row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
```

so instead did this:

JQUERY / JS:

```
row.child('<div class="child-container">'+contactInfo + editorRooms+'</div>').show();
tr.addClass('shown');
tr.next('tr').addClass('open'); //used to determine the new row
$('div.child-container', row.child()).slideDown();
```

CSS:

```
table.dataTable .child-container
{  
    display: none;
    min-height:150px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr.open > td 
{
    padding: 0;
}
```

For some reason it shows the table 'contactInfo', then slides to the end of the fixed height 'child-container'?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `slideDown()` doesnt initilise below the `min-height` value of 150px. So was just viewing the last 50px being slided. I removed the style to get a full slide effect.